# I got a string containing `\x00\x07` how to remove it

Tags: ruby

I got a string

> "\x00\x00\x007{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid
>   request\"}"

I want to clean up the string into

```
"{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
```

How to write an general case to filter something starts with `\x`  ?

Answer (score 1):

If `\x##` are truly literals, use `string.gsub(/\\x\d+/, "")`:

```
> t = "\\x00\\x00\\x007{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
=> "\\x00\\x00\\x007{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}
string.gsub(/\\x[\da-f]+/i, "")
=> "{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
```

`string.sub(/^[^{]*/, "")` on the other hand would remove everything before the first `{`:

```
> t = "\x00\x00\x007{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
=> "\u0000\u0000\u00007{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
> t.sub(/^[^{]*/, "")
=> "{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
```

And to only remove `\x00` and `\x07` (non-literal), use `string.gsub(/\x00|\x07/, "")`
Or `string.gsub(/[\x00\x07]/, "")`:

```
> t = "\x00\x00\x07{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
=> "\u0000\u0000\a{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
> t.gsub(/\x00|\x07/, "")
=> "{\"request\":\"Cameralogout\",\"response\":\"Invalid request\"}"
```

Comment: `/\\x\d+/` should be `/\\x[\da-f]+/i`. because after `\x`, hexadecimal digits can come.

Comment: @falsetru The example's a bit misleading. I think it was a typo that `\x07` was made `\x007`. I forwarded your answer thanks.